# List custom taxonomies associated to an author's posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy, author

On the author template, I would like to display a list of the custom taxonomies associated to the posts written by that author.

In details:
I have a "clubs" taxonomy, which is non-hierarchical and applies to Posts.

On the author template, I need to display a list of the "clubs" used by that author's Posts, as links. In this manner, i can list the clubs to which this author participates in.

Is that possible?

Comment: Did you tried anything ? You can try first getting all of the post ids by author and then `wp_get_object_terms` functions to retrieve the terms by taxonomy and object_ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First grab the post ids by the author, and then the terms.

```
$author_id = '1234';
$taxonomy = 'clubs';

$post_ids = get_posts('fields=ids&post_type=post&post_status=publish&showposts=-1&author='. $author_id );
$clubs = wp_get_object_terms($post_ids, array($taxonomy));

$html = '<ul>';
foreach( $clubs as $club )
{
    $html .= sprintf( 
        '<li><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></li>',
        get_term_link($club, $taxonomy),
        $club->name
    );
}
$html .= '</ul>';

echo $html;
```

Comment: Hello Shazzad, Thank you it works quite nicely, except that if a tag has been used in 2 posts, it will appear twice. But you've sent me in the right direction, so i'll pick this up as the right answer.